# PHP optimization - include() or not

Tags: php

I have two optimization question about the function include.

1. Is it better to use a single php file and include it or use several little files and include them? Which one will be faster?
2. For example, I use a PHP file with `mysql_connect` and all the db connection stuff. Then I include it when I need it. But will it be faster to just write the code when I need it and not include anything?

Also if someone has the actual numbers, I will be a nice plus.

Comment: There is so little overhead for `include` that you should just do whatever is easiest and most maintainable for you.

Comment: I can't answer your question but I can say you probably won't notice any significant performance difference and shouldn't worry about little things like this. Structure it in a way that's understandable.

Comment: _Premature optimization is the root of all evil._ -- Donald Knuth

Comment: Well, when I see optimization for quotes and double quotes to save micro seconds, I wondered if I couldn't save any here.

Comment: Just because some developers believe that single and double quotes will make a difference to the performance of their applications, doesn't mean that it will make a difference - or that other micro-optimizations should be used at the cost of code readability

Comment: There still isn't an answer to this, just a bunch of people trying to impress their code design principles. If the question included that then fair enough, but it doesn't ask "Which would be better".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. The differences will be trivial.
2. [Don't repeat yourself.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) Do not put connection information in each file over and over again. Including sounds fine in your case.
3. Stop making use of `mysql_*()`. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

You're talking about micro-optimalisation, while it's probably better to start thinking about object oriented programming instead.

Comment: If I could give +3 to this (one for each bullet point), I would. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Pick any decent-sized open source project. Like WordPress, Joomla, Drupal for instance. Now check if they have a single gigantic-everything-goes-in-there file or if they have split it into small, maintainable components.

Answer: favor maintainability first. When you hit a bottleneck, you'll be able to find it and address in a much easier way.

Answer (score -1):

PHP include()'s are processed server side, not by the browser or anywhere else so the difference in performance would be negligible. If it helps you keep your code more organized you should include your DB connection info, there won't be a noticeable speed difference.